# Javascript error: replaceChild - Node not found

Tags: javascript

I am using the below code to swap two arrays of elements. In the last iteration, it is throwing the NodeNotFound error.

```
for (x=0; x<resultArr.length; x++) {    
        //allTR[x].swapNode(colArr[resultArr[x]])
        swapNodes(allTR[x],colArr[resultArr[x]]);
    }
    function swapNodes(item1,item2)
    {
        var itemtmp = item1.cloneNode(1);
        var parent = item1.parentNode;
        item2 = parent.replaceChild(itemtmp,item2);
        parent.replaceChild(item2,item1);
        parent.replaceChild(item1,itemtmp);
        itemtmp = null;
    }
```

While I was debugging throw firebug, during the last iteration, while I hover on second line of swapNodes function item1.parentNode was showing null. Then item2=parent.replaceChild(itemtmp,item2) executed well. 
The next line throws me the exception in console but expected functionality worked well.

I have to make work the functionality without this script error. Please help me on the issue.

Comment: According to the error and the debuggin results the parent (or perhaps the item itself) is null or undefined... Provide more code, otherweise its impossible to help you...

Comment: @MarvinEmilBrach In the last iteration, item1 was having value. But when I hover item1.parentNode, the parentNode alone was showing null. How can i handle this scenario

Answer (score 0):

I made the below code change, and the functionality worked well without script error.

```
function swapNodes(a, b){
        var pa1= a.parentNode, pa2= b.parentNode, sib= b.nextSibling;
        if(sib=== a) sib= sib.nextSibling;
        pa1.replaceChild(b, a);
        if(sib) pa2.insertBefore(a, sib);
        else pa2.appendChild(a);
        return true;
    }
```